# How to merge two object values with same keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object, array-merge

I am getting response as

```
data [4] { {
_id:"1" description:"desc" languageId:"5" title:"ttitle" } { [1]:
_id:"2" description:"desc1" languageId:"4" title:"title2" } { [2]:
_id:"3" description:"desc3" languageId:"4" title:"title2" } [3]:
_id:"4" description:"desc4" languageId:"4" title:"title2" } }
```

and need to split this as

```
 {
    [0]:Object
    description:"desc"
    title:"ttitle"
    description1:"desc1"
    title1:"title2"
    }
    {
    [1]:Object
    description:"desc3"
    title:"ttitle"
    description1:"desc4"
    title1:"title2"
    }
```

This is angularjs. Please help. I have tried using push and merge. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Object assign?
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell for sure what you were asking.  Is this what you wanted?

http://plnkr.co/edit/yWc36FmiBs6gMaXBq9on?p=preview

```
function split(data) {
  var results = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    var j = i + 1;

    var result = {
      description: data[i].description,
      description1: data[j].description,
      title: data[i].title,
      title1: data[j].title,
    };

    results.push(result);
  }

  return results;
}
```

Example input:

```
  var data = [{
    _id: "1",
    description: "desc",
    languageId: "5",
    title: "ttitle"
  }, {
    _id: "2",
    description: "desc1",
    languageId: "4",
    title: "title2"
  }, {
    _id: "3",
    description: "desc3",
    languageId: "4",
    title: "title2"
  }, {
    _id: "4",
    description: "desc4",
    languageId: "4",
    title: "title2"
  }];
```

Example output:

```
[{
  "description": "desc",
  "description1": "desc1",
  "title": "ttitle",
  "title1": "title2"
}, {
  "description": "desc3",
  "description1": "desc4",
  "title": "title2",
  "title1": "title2"
}]
```